# mutiple sorting rule with IComparable and IComparer?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm new to C#, just a question on how to use IComparable and IComparer properly. Let's say we have the following class:

```
public class Student
{
    int score;
    string name;
}
```

and I want to sort by socre (desc) first then sort by name (asc).

Now assume that I can't access to the Student class, so I can only use IComparer
so I have to make one help class(let's say it is called StudentComparer) and put the same logic into

```
public class StudentComparer: IComparer
{
   int Compare(object o1, object o2)
   {
      Student s1 = o1 as Student;
      Student s2 = o2 as Student;
      // not checking null for simplicity
      if (s1.score == s2.score)
         return String.Compare(s1.name, s2.name);
      else if (s1.score < s2.score)
           return -1
      else
      return 1
   }
}
```

Here is my question, if I just need to use a single rule later, for example, sometimes just sort by name and sometimes just sort by score. So I have to make another two help classes(ScoreComparer and NameComparer) that implement IComparer, which have duplicated code in StudentComparer as

```
public class ScoreComparer : IComparer
{
   int Compare(object o1, object o2)
   {
      //half logic of StudentComparer
   }
}

public class NameComparer: IComparer
{
   int Compare(object o1, object o2)
   {
      //half logic of StudentComparer
   }
}
```

my case is pretty simple, image that if there is a complicated case, each comparer consist of hundreds line of code,so how can I avoid duplicated code? or is it a way to combine multiple Comparer A, B, C, D ... into a common Comparer so that it check A,B,C,D in sequence, just like order by clause in SQL

Comment: They won't have "duplicated code", clearly the Compare() method will be different.

Comment: You can use order by Linq method... To void writing comparer...

Comment: @HansPassant  there will be duplicated code

Comment: SO will still be available once you need to deal with a "complicated case".  And haven't thought of putting common code in a base class or static methods.  Do avoid writing .NET 1.0 code, create an `IComparer<Student>` instead.  Less needless code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back in the days before linq, I used to use comparers a lot.
The way I've handled different sort options was by specifying these options in the constructor of the comparer implementation and then use that information in the `Compare` method.

Lucky for us, we now have linq so this entire thing can be done with a single, fluent line of code:

```
// sortedStudents is an IEnumerable<Student> sorted by score and name.
var sortedStudents = students.OrderBy(s => s.Score).ThenBy(s => s.Name);
```

However, if for some reason you need to work the old-fashion way, using comparers and stuff like that, here is how I would handle this back then:

```
internal enum CompareBy
{
    NameOnly,
    ScoreAndName
}

public class StudentComparer: IComparer<Student>
{

    private CompareBy _compareBy
    public StudentComparer(CompareBy compareBy)
    {
        _compareBy = compareBy;
    }

    public int Compare(Student s1, Student s2)
    {
        // not checking null for simplicity

        var nameCompare = string.Compare(s1.name, s2.name);
        if(_compareBy == NameOnly)
        {
            return nameCompare;
        }
        // since there are only two members in the enum it's safe to write it like this.
        // if the enum grows, you must change the code.
        if (s1.score == s2.score)
        {
            return nameCompare;
        }
        else if (s1.score < s2.score)
        {
            return -1
        }
        return 1
   }
}
```